# How to put a windows installable program on Heroku for user download in a Rails web application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, executable

I have a rails web application that contains a Windows executable file the user can download and install on his PC. This program will communicate with certain peripherals on the user's PC using web services to the web application.

Where should I put such a program in my Rails tree, and how should I make this "available" for users to download?

Comment: Everything under `public/` is available to the browser, however I would suggest considering CDN or similar solution.

Comment: @Michael: if you add your comment as an answer, I will accept it. Works perfect!

Comment: It's too basic for SO in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

**Assets**

Alternatively to putting them in the `public` dir, you may wish to create a `downlods` folder in the asset pipeline: `/app/assets/downloads`

This will give you the ability to call `downloads_path`, and precompile each file.

In order to get this to work, you'll be best creating a `helper` method like this:

```
#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
def downloads_path path
    asset_path("/downloads/#{path}")
end

#app/views/application/index.html.erb
<%= downloads_path("download.exe") %>
```

---

This has the added benefit of allowing you to precompile the files, and having them accessible from the likes of CDN's, as `Michael Szyndel` recommended

Comment: Rich - what would be the benefit of precompiling these files?